# How to detect rectangles and rotate them in the correct direction in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, omr

I have block code like this.

```
def crop_image(self,img):
        cnts,gray_img = self.pre_processing_img(img)
        ans_blocks = []
        x_old, y_old, w_old, h_old = 0, 0, 0, 0

        if len(cnts) > 0:
            cnts = sorted(cnts, key=self.get_x_ver1)
            for i, c in enumerate(cnts):
                x_curr, y_curr, w_curr, h_curr = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                if w_curr * h_curr > 100000 and w_curr < h_curr:
                    check_xy_min = x_curr * y_curr - x_old * y_old
                    check_xy_max = (x_curr + w_curr) * (y_curr + h_curr) - (x_old + w_old) * (y_old + h_old)

                    if len(ans_blocks) == 0:
                        cv2.imshow("test", gray_img[y_curr:y_curr + h_curr, x_curr:x_curr + w_curr])
                        cv2.waitKey(0)
                        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                        ans_blocks.append(
                            (gray_img[y_curr:y_curr + h_curr, x_curr:x_curr + w_curr],[x_curr,y_curr,w_curr,h_curr]))
                        x_old,y_old,w_old,h_old = x_curr,y_curr,w_curr,h_curr

                    elif check_xy_min > 20000 and check_xy_max > 20000:
                        ans_blocks.append(
                            (gray_img[y_curr:y_curr + h_curr, x_curr:x_curr + w_curr],[x_curr,y_curr,w_curr,h_curr]))
                        x_old,y_old,w_old,h_old = x_curr,y_curr,w_curr,h_curr

            sorted_ans_blocks = sorted(ans_blocks, key=self.get_x)
            return sorted_ans_blocks
```

And the correct image test should be like this
[image]

But in some cases it returns this image depending on the input image
[image]

Sorry for the lack of information.
This is the scanned photo (happiest case)
[image]

And this is the input photo (the image from camera taked)
[image]
How can I detect misaligned images and rotate them to the correct position as I want them to be?

Comment: Align your image first to the coordinate axes.  If you have a good image that is properly aligned or have a clean image that you can scale, you can align to that one.

Comment: I just added information about the input images, how can I align to that one. Many thanks for all the help

Comment: Your last image is warped in complex way. It cannot be aligned by a simple rotation or affine or perspective transformation.  How was that image acquired?  If you have images that have been scanned on a flat-bed scanner then a simple affine would  be sufficient. You might possibly get by using a perspective transform to aligned each of the 4 major columns in the last image to the reference image.

Comment: Better to scan with a flat-bed scanner than to take such poor scans or photographs from a camera with such bad distortion. What kind of camera did you use?  It is taking terrible images. They are quite distorted and also very pink.

Comment: Thank you for your response, in my case the happiest situation is that the photo has been scanned. The last image is a photo taken by a user and I have to process that image, so I want to realign the corner of the rectangle like the first image once the rectangles have been removed.

Comment: I resized the last photo so I could upload it here because it's over 2MB in size, so it looks pretty bad.

Comment: Why are you getting pictures of tests from the users? That does not make sense to me. You have lost control and can get garbage.  But if you can get each of the columns as separate images, then you can find the corners of the columns and use a perspective warp to align them.

Comment: I'm following your direction, but the problem is I don't know how to detect the rectangle in the cropped image then align it.

Comment: Look at my picture 2, you can see that I have to align the rectangle to the right direction -> if I can do that, the application will run perfectly

Comment: those pictures are way too deformed to be "easy" to rectify. this is not a simple task. its scope is way beyond a simple question on Stack Overflow. also, any viable solution has commercial value. you're either a beginner who has no idea how complex this task is, or you're working on this for a commercial application.

Comment: solution sketch: non-linear warp using either some mesh or a smoothed per-pixel warp map. alignment requires iteration. can be initialized from feature matches (needs filtering). if you're lucky, init using a linear approximation gets you close enough to iterate. if not, the feature matches may require filtering (inlier/outlier) using a kernel/distance filter.

Comment: be prepared to discard user input that is too blurry or badly lit. your last picture fails in both criteria. I see motion blur as well as overexposure. AND the boxes look like their lines have been redrawn with a pen. they're way thicker than the reference picture. -- also: where are those black rectangles that are supposed to sit on the borders of the sheet? they are missing in that photo. they exist precisely for such applications. they are registration marks. they'll help a little in this situation but with those alone, from a photo, you can't recover the areas that were penciled in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and solutions. I chose the method that when the input image is too blurry or the rectangle cannot be detected, I will ignore it instead of trying to process it.

Comment: If you have separated the columns as in your very first and second images. You can "turn" the second image by getting the contours of the first and second images. Then get the rotated bounding boxes of the second and the simple bounding box of the first. Then get the 4 corners from the bounding boxes and uses those to do a perspective or perhaps an affine warp.  See cv2.minAreaRect() for the rotated bounding box, cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() to find the perspective xform from the 4 corners and cv2.warpPerspective() to do the perspective warp

Comment: How to implement that, can you help me, I'm not very clear about that idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic concept to warp the distorted column to match the vertical column in Python/OpenCV.

Given one column, do the following:

- Read the reference and distorted images
- Since you posted screen captures, crop the tops off and also any black on the sides
- Threshold on the black lines using cv2.inRange() on both cropped images
- Get the largest contour of the reference image
- Get its bounding box and computed the four corners in clockwise fashion from the top-left. So TL, TR, BR, BL
- Get the largest contour of the distorted image
- Compute is rotated bounding rectangle using cv2.minAreaRect()
- Then get the box point from the rotated rectangle
- Then compute the vectors from the center of the rotated rectangle to these box points and get the angle of the vector.
- Then sort the box points by their vector angle
- Then separate the sorted points into TL, TR, BR, BL order
- Then compute the perspective transform matrix from the two sets of 4 corners.
- Then warp the distorted image using the matrix to align the distorted image with the reference image.
- Then save the results

Reference Image (test1.png):

[image]

Distorted Image (test2.png):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read the reference image
ref = cv2.imread('test1.png')
rh, rw = ref.shape[:2]

# read the distorted image
dtd = cv2.imread('test2.png')
dh, dw = dtd.shape[:2]

# crop the tops which should not really be there and black sides
cref = ref[56:rh-7, 5:rw-7]
crh, crw = cref.shape[:2]
print(cref.shape)
cdtd = dtd[57:dh-5, 0:dw]
cdh, cdw = cdtd.shape[:2]
print(cdtd.shape)
print('')

# threshold on black lines
lower = (0,0,0)
upper = (175,175,175)
tref = cv2.inRange(cref, lower, upper)
lower = (0,0,0)
upper = (150,150,150)
tdtd = cv2.inRange(cdtd, lower, upper)

# get largest contour of tref and its axis aligned bounding box
contours = cv2.findContours(tref, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
ref_cntr = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
xr,yr,wr,hr = cv2.boundingRect(ref_cntr)

# get 4 corners clockwise from top-left: TL, TR, BR, BL
rtl = (xr,yr)
rtr = (xr+wr,yr)
rbr = (xr+wr,yr+hr)
rbl = (xr,yr+hr)
print(rtl, rtr, rbr, rbl)
print('')
ref_cimg = cref.copy()
cv2.drawContours(ref_cimg, [ref_cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 2)

# get largest contour of tdtd and its rotated bounding box
contours = cv2.findContours(tdtd, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
dtd_cntr = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(dtd_cntr)
(center), (width,height), angle = rotrect
box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
boxpts = np.intp(box)
dtd_cimg = cdtd.copy()
cv2.drawContours(dtd_cimg, [dtd_cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.drawContours(dtd_cimg,[boxpts],0,(0,255,0),2)

# Get box points relative to the center of rotate rect and the angles of the vector from center to point
(cx,cy) = (center)
sort_info = []
for pt in box:
    [px,py] = pt
    pxc = px - cx
    pyc = py - cy
    ang = (180/math.pi)*math.atan2(pyc,pxc)
    sort_info.append([px,py,ang])
    #print(px, py, ang)
    #print('')

# sort by angle
def takeThird(elem):
    return elem[2]
sort_info.sort(key=takeThird, reverse=False)
#print(sort_info)

# get 4 corners clockwise from top-left: TL, TR, BR, BL
x_info = []
y_info = []
for i in range(0,4):    
    [x,y,ang] = sort_info[i]
    x_info.append(x)
    y_info.append(y)
dtl = (x_info[0],y_info[0])
dtr = (x_info[1],y_info[1])
dbr = (x_info[2],y_info[2])
dbl = (x_info[3],y_info[3])
print(dtl, dtr, dbr, dbl)

# get perspective warp
ref_pts = np.float32([ [rtl], [rtr], [rbr], [rbl] ])
dtd_pts = np.float32([ [dtl], [dtr], [dbr], [dbl] ])
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(dtd_pts, ref_pts)

# do perspective transformation setting area outside input to black
dtd_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(cdtd, matrix, (crw,crh), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(255,255,255))

# Save results
cv2.imwrite('test1_thresh.jpg', tref)
cv2.imwrite('test2_thresh.jpg', tdtd)
cv2.imwrite('test1_contour.jpg', ref_cimg)
cv2.imwrite('test2_contour.jpg', dtd_cimg)
cv2.imwrite('test1_cropped.jpg', cref)
cv2.imwrite('test2_warped.jpg', dtd_warped)

# show results
cv2.imshow('ref thresh', tref)
cv2.imshow('dtd thresh', tdtd)
cv2.imshow('ref contour', ref_cimg)
cv2.imshow('dtd contour', dtd_cimg)
cv2.imshow('dtd warped', dtd_warped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded Reference Image(after crop):

[image]

Thresholded Distorted Image (after crop):

[image]

Contour Image for Reference Image:

[image]

Contour Image and Rotated Rectangle for Distorted Image:

[image]

Cropped Reference Image for comparison:

[image]

Warped Distorted image to match cropped reference:

[image]

(With your large multi-column tests with red lines, get all the contours. Then filter them by area and or perimeter to separate out the 4 main columns.  Then loop over each column and do the above processing.)